# React onPress execute immediately ( render time) , but once replace with arrow function it does not work

Tags: react-native

```js
export const Focus = ({addSubject})=>{

const [tempValue, setTempValue] = useState(null);

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}> 
     <View style={styles.titleContainer}> 
    <Text style={styles.title}> What are you going to focus on....?</Text>
     <View style={styles.inputcontainer}> 
    <TextInput style ={{flex:1, marginRight:10}}  
    onSubmitEditing ={
      ({nativeEvent}) => {
        setTempValue(nativeEvent.text+'0000')
      }
    }
    />
       <RoundedButton title ='+' onPress={
         addSubject(tempValue) 
         }/> 
        
       </View>
     </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Just after entering data, once hit the 'return' it submit entered "text+0000"

but once replace with

```js
 <RoundedButton title ='+' onPress={
         ()=>{ addSubject(tempValue)}
         }/>
```

on press is not working

*** I'm testing this on on Expo web

What is the reason for this behavior and what is the solution to make it work once press the button.

Comment: `onPress={addSubject(tempValue)}` really isnt what you want. The reason it appears to work is because the expression passed to`onPress` is being evaluated at the start of every render, meaning that `addSubject(tempValue)` is being executed whether the the button is pressed or not. As of why it stop working when you wrapped the expression in a function, we dont really have enough information to safely say. For an example, we dont know what `addSubject` does, or how `RoundedButton` handles its `onPress` prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without braces, then only it will return the addSubject function

```
<RoundedButton 
  title ='+' 
  onPress={()=> addSubject(tempValue)}
/>
```